# In chrome developer tools : how can I see in the Name column , the path also?

Tags: google-chrome, http

In chrome developer tools : how can I see in the Name column , the path also beside the name (below the name)?

Answer (score 0):

If it is from **Network**

If you select the **name result** from the **Name** column a **Headers** tab will appear beside to that. in that you could see the **Request URL** path